# Botframework hide messages in group chat

Tags: botframework

How in group chat

1. hide message to bot -- @mybot xxx?
2. send message from bot only to one user of group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the channels that support bots being members of a group allow users to explicitly block a bot from getting messages, though some require that the bot is @mentioned in order to get any message sent in a group.

For those that support Direct Messages, the Bot can send a message to a single user as follows:

```
    var response = await activityContext.ConnectorAPI.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(activity.Recipient, activity.From);

    var reply = activity.CreateReply($"This is a direct message to {activity.From.Name ?? activity.From.Id} : {activity.Text}");
    reply.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: response.Id);
    reply.ReplyToId = null;

    await activityContext.ConnectorAPI.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(reply);
```